# How to delete the contacts saved in mobile?

Tags: contacts, delete

How to delete the contacts saved in mobile?

In the contacts in mobile memory

mobile model : **vivo V5**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to contact option and click Edit option in the top-left

And select the contact and delete